# Merge and edit 2 UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I was looking around to find a solution but I didn’t. 
Actually I have a block of code that merge 2 image in one. 
It’s like I take a photo and the apply a .png on it.

But I would like to let the user move the top image in order to choose the position before save the image

Thanks for any possible help to how I could do it

Here is my func:

```
func mergeFrame(bottomImage: UIImage, topImage: UIImage) -> UIImage{

    let size = CGSize(width: bottomImage.size.width, height: bottomImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    bottomImage.draw(in: areaSize)

    topImage.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 0.8)

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: What part of this are you having problems with? Letting the user drag the top image around? Do you want the parts of the top image that the user drags off of the other image to be clipped?

Comment: Yes actually I have no idea how to enable the user to drag and drop the top image before join them

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move the top image, the topImage should have a flexible drawing area.

`topImage.draw(in: topArea, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 0.8)`

Then use an UIPanGesture to change the topAread.origin base on the gesture.translation during State.Changed.

In State.End of the gesture,  call posted mergeFrame(::) to get the composed image.

Hope you got it.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit more? I am a newbie

Comment: I mean just change the `areaSize` of top image to `topArea`, which is a real portion of topView. Also you can use two UIImageViews. One is hold the bottomImage, the other is top image. Adding a Pangesture to top UIImageView to move it over the bottom imageView. When the position is good, just release the gesture (.ended) and put the composed image into a result UIImageView.